# What is the best practice around application routes in Flask?

Tags: flask

I've inherited the maintenance of a Flask app and there seems to be a lot of inconsistencies around the route syntax convention. In other words the project contains multiple instances of

```
@app.route(".....")
@app.get(".....")
@app.route("....." methods=[POST])
@app.post(".....")
```

Etc. It's my understanding that

```
@app.get() == @app.route(methods=[GET]) == @app.route()
```

And

```
@app.post() == @app.route(methods=[POST])
```

Are there subtle differences I am missing, or are these functionally equivalent? Is one method considered standard convention/best practice over another?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `@app.post(‘…’)` and `@app.route(‘…’, methods=[‘POST’])`. If you look at the flask source code at https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/src/flask/sansio/scaffold.py you will see that the app.post, app.parch, app.put, app.get and app.delete methods all call app.route internally. The app.route syntax has been present since the very beginning with the individual method calls being added much more recently to simplify the development of APIs.